# material design two line list in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, material-design

this might be a duplicate question but I'm wondering how to use the two-line list from "material design" on a recycler view. I can't figure it out, and I can't find anything on Youtube and Stackoverflow after searching for about an hour.

I want to create something like the picture below.

[image: list example]

This image is directly from the website itself: https://material.io/components/lists

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend taking a tutorial on how to implement lists. Any will do, but this is the official one: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to do so, it would suffice to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` as the row layout in your Adapter. Although it won't have the overflow menu icon. I don't know if you are trying to replicate that exact same list you posted.

But honestly, I don't know what's your Android experience. Do you have a working understanding of RecyclerViews and Adapters?

The link you provided shows Material Design guidelines. It doesn't necessarily mean that those lists and functionalities are ready to use with any basic Adapter you implement. For complex rows, you need to provide the layout, as well as implement functionality to user-initiated events such as click listeners, swipes, drags, etc.

For me, codelabs are always a good place to start with some hands-on exercise.

RecyclerView codelab:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals&authuser=1#0

Comment: thanks for the comment, yeah i'm trying to make to "replicate" it, but I think I've got an idea on what to do now, thanks!